# Can't get Etag when updating SharePoint lists using jQuery and listdata.svc

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint-2010

So I'm using jQuery to interact with SharePoint's Rest Services (i.e. listdata.svc).  When I call listdata.svc to update an existing item
The update works fine but I can't get at the new ETag that listdata.svc sent back for the item. The HTTP Status sent back in the response is 204 (No Content).  The new ETag is sent in an 'ETag' header in the response ( I can see it clearly in Fiddler).  But in the "success:"  or "complete:"  callbacks of my jQuery Ajax calls, if I call  jqXHR.getResponseHeader("ETag") it always returns null. It returns null for any header Ii ask for. If I call  jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders() it returns an empty string.

I have the same issue  when I add a record. After adding the record, listdata.svc sends back the ETag, as well as the new Item's URL in the request headers, which I cannot get at!

I'm using the jQuery-1.7.2, Internet Explorer version 8.0.7601.17514 and SharePoint 2010 with SP1. Client OS is windows 7.

I recreated the issue in a simple script that tries to update the title of a Task in the Tasks List of a new TeamSite called resttest. Code is shown below.

Does anyone know of a fix or a workaround to this issue? I tested to see if I get I get the same results with a native XMLHttpRequest and that too fails. I get an HTTP STATUS of 1223 and client.getResponseHeader("ETag") retuns an empty string.  The native code is shown further down below.

I tested tis in IE9 and I get the same bad results results.
I tested int in both Chome and Firefox  (using the XMLHttpRequest version) and client.getResponseHeader("ETag")  retuns the ETAG! in Both Browsers! (Too bad my yCOmpany Standard is IE!).

Here’s the code using jQuery:

```
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("doit");
function doit(){
debugger;
$.ajax({
      url: "http://myServerName/resttest/_vti_bin/listData.svc/Tasks(1)",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      datatype: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,    
      global:false,
      processData:false,
      data:"{Title:'Updated title'}",
      beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "PUT");
                    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("If-Match", 'W/"2"');  // this must be set to the "Current" value of the etag on the server (I can get to it by calling http://myServerName/resttest/_vti_bin/listData.svc/Tasks(1)) from a browser
           },
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            },
      complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                debugger;
                var x = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("ETag"); // this returns null , even though i see ETag: W/"2" in the headers in fiddler!
                var y = this.xhr();
                var z = y.getAllResponseHeaders();
                var kjh = y.getResponseHeader("ETag");
            },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                alert('Something bad happened. Stopping');
            }
    });
}
```

Here are the resposne headers from Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Cache-Control: no-cache
ETag: W/"2"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: d0fc56f0-8277-469a-a290-e7d3de96295d
Set-Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={b6a87457-6e7d-4de0-9c8d-f56add57f6f4}; path=/
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={b6a87457-6e7d-4de0-9c8d-f56add57f6f4}; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6106
Date: Thu, 07 Jun 2012 18:25:14 GMT
```

Here’s the code using an XMLHttpRequest:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("doit");
function doit() {
    debugger;
    var url = "http://sgm1dsps06/resttest/_vti_bin/listData.svc/Tasks(1)";
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open("POST", url, false);
    client.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "PUT");
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    client.setRequestHeader("If-Match", 'W/"5"');  // this must be set to the "Current" value of the etag on the server (I can get to it by calling http://sgm1dsps06/resttest/_vti_bin/listData.svc/Tasks(1)) from a browser
    client.send("{Title:'Updated title'}");
   {
       alert("Status is : " + client.status + " " + client.statusText + ".");  //the status is always 1223
       var etag = client.getResponseHeader("ETag");
       if (etag == null)
           alert("etag is null"); 
       else
           alert("Etag is " + etag); // the etag is alwasys an empty string

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a viable solution to this problem. Since we can't get at the http headers returned by the original PUT request, I just issued a new query to the resource from within the original 'PUT' request's success  callback

>

```
 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("doit");
function doit(){
debugger;
$.ajax({
      url: "http://sgm1dsps06/resttest/_vti_bin/listData.svc/Tasks(1)",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      datatype: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,    
      global:false,
      processData:false,
      data:"{Title:'Updated title'}",
      beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "PUT");
                    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("If-Match", 'W/"3"');  // this must be set to the "Current" value of the etag on the server (I can get to it by calling http://sgm1dsps06/resttest/_vti_bin/listData.svc/Tasks(1)) from a browser
           },
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            },
      complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
               debugger;
                if (jqXHR.status === 204) {
                    // requery the resource to get the new etag // this is due to a bug in ie that drops all headers associated with an http 204
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        datatype: 'json',
                        url: this.url,
                        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            var etag = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("ETag");
                            alert(etag);
                        }
                    }
                  }
            },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                                }
    });
}
```